# Как правильно хранить в бд себестоимость и ндс товара

Tags: delphi, база-данных, проектирование

Есть программа склада.
Interbase 2009. В бд есть таблицы Income(приход), Outcome(расход).....

**Income**(приход):

- Cost(себестоимость),
- Vat(ндс, который плачу при покупке),
- IncomeDate(дата прихода),
- Qty(кол-во прихода),
- QtyCurr(кол-во сейчас).

Допустим, 01/11/2016 встал на учёт как плательщик ндс-а. Но **на этот момент есть остатки от старых приходов.** В старых записях, на которых есть остатки для тех товаров, которые облагаются ндс-ом, если изменять цифры себестоимости и ндс-а, например, если цена была 2долл. и и был распределен так:

```
Cost-2; Vat-0
```

сейчас станет

```
Cost-1.695; vat-0.305.
```

Но тогда прибыль от старых продаж (до 01/11/16) будет посчитано неправильно- вместо (продаж.цена без ндс-2) будет (продаж.цена без ндс-1,695)!

Какие изменения можно сделать в бд, а не в запросах, чтобы обойти эту проблему?

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Списывать старый остаток с 0 НДС-ом и принять то же количество с ндс-ом и другой себестоимостью?
   Но тогда в таблице-"шапке" приходов для каждой фирмы появится 2 записи(первый-старый и второй-нового прихода после списывания остатка ) , а приход был всего один.
2. В бд добавить таблицу(VatVersion) с периодом времены.
   то есть, конечная закупочная цена(InPrice),себестоимость и ндс останется в таблице записей прихода(Income).

   ```
   Income: Income_id,IncomeDate, cost, vat, Qty, InPrice...
   VatVersion: id,StartDate, EndDate,VatPayable(0 or 1).
   ```

   Но тогда получается что на старые остатки в Income продолжаю хранить товар старой себестоимостью и нулевым ндс-ом!!!
3. Не хранить в бд себестоимость и ндс, а посчитать в программе. Для этого создать таблицу как в варианте 2 с периодами времени и флагом налогообложения (тратит-1, не тратит-0).

Покритикуйте эти варианты и предлагайте другое решение если такое есть.

Comment: создаете таблицу "версионности" с датой и ндсом на эту дату соответственно все расчет проводите используя эту таблицу

Comment: @Виктор, спасибо за ответ. Прочитайте, пожалуйста, вариант 2. Если вы это имели ввиду тогда получается что на старые остатки в Income продолжаю хранить товар старой себестоимостью и нулевым ндс-ом!!! 
Например, себестоимость была10 и ндс 0, а после вставания на учёт, посколько vatpayable=1, себестоимость при продаже  8.47
 и ндс 1,53. А в бд всеравно хранятся старые цены- 10 и 0!!!